# Using absoluteness and other arguments for something elementarity has covered.

Tags: general-topology, logic, set-theory, model-theory

[image]

In the image included here (from Dow's Introduction to Applications of Elementary Submodels) absoluteness is used to argue that if M "thinks" that B is a base for $(X,\tau)$ then $H(\Theta)$ does too. But doesn't this follow from elementarity? And doesn't this also imply that $H(\Theta)$ thinks $B$ is point countable as well? Why aren't the lines in pink and green superfluous?

Comment: I agree - unless I'm missing something, this seems superfluous.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Was your comment before or after my edit?

Comment: After. (Your edit was 19 minutes ago, my comment was 10 minutes ago.)

Comment: And $\mathcal{T}$ is itself a base for a topology (not the topology itself), as Dow remarks himself at the beginning this introduction.

Comment: The green part uses that countable sets are the same between $H(\theta)$ and $M$ (from 1.6 IIRC).